# Codeigniter 4 : "Attempt to read property 'name' on array" error when executing ->findAll() on the BaseBuilder

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

this is my first time exploring Codeigniter 4 and I follow some tutorials to understand the basic crud process.

Below are my controller where the model query is used.

```
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use CodeIgniter\RESTful\ResourcePresenter;

class Project extends ResourcePresenter
{

protected $modelName = 'App\Models\ProjectModel';

public function index()
    {

    return view('projects/index', ['projects' => $this->model->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')->findAll()]);
    }
}
```

Then below are the index page where I want to display the list and the part where I have a problem.

```
<?php foreach ($projects as $project) : ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?= $project->name ?></td>
                    <td><?= $project->description ?></td>
                    <td>
                        <form action="<?php echo base_url('/projects/delete/' . $project->id); ?>" method="post">
                            <a class="btn btn-outline-info" href="<?php echo base_url('/projects/show/' . $project->id); ?>">
                                Show
                            </a>
                            <a class="btn btn-outline-success" href="<?php echo base_url('/projects/edit/' . $project->id); ?>">
                                Edit
                            </a>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger">Delete</button>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

'name' and 'description' are the column names stored in the database.

Can anyone help me check whether the problem is because of code or another external factor since my friend who tried the same tutorial succeeded even though the code is the same?

Below are the errors that show up.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`->findAll()` returns an array of elements](https://github.com/codeigniter4/CodeIgniter4/blob/24f67ea95aa463771360eb38f627675af2fda3d6/system/BaseModel.php#L595).

Instead of: ❌

```php
  <td><?= $project->name ?></td>
  <td><?= $project->description ?></td>
```

Use this: ✅

```php
  <td><?= $project['name'] ?></td>
  <td><?= $project['description'] ?></td>
```

*Do the same for other sections. I.e :`$project->id`.*

Comment: Thank you for the help. It help solve my confusion. I need to change the return type in the model class to object if I don't want the return in array value.